# td extra padding on top in Chrome gmail compose

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-table

I'm building a chrome extension that adds a custom text next to gmail's send button. The problem is, a extra spacing is added on top too.

The effect is like this:

[image: Extra padding above]

The html is this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="n1tfz">
      <td class="gU Up">
        <div id=":ly" class="J-J5-Ji">
          <div id=":my" class="J-J5-Ji"></div>
          <div id=":nq" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3" role="button" tabindex="1"  data-tooltip="Send ‪(⌘Enter)‬" aria-label="Send ‪(⌘Enter)‬" data-tooltip-delay="800" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Send</div>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td id="my-send-btn">
        <span id="my-status">OFF</span>
      </td>
...
```

Even if I just duplicate the send button, the same effect still happens. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Experiment with various style properties. Do `font-size`, `line-height`, `padding-top` and `margin-top` have any effect? Or see what happens if you use a wrapper element that has `height:0` and `overflow:visible`. Things like that.

Comment: @MrLister I have tried these. The issue is, even if I copy the send button exactly, with all the styling & children, there's still extra padding on top.